# 2D Vectors Segmentation Fault:push_back

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

I am trying to solve a problem dealing with *2d vectors* array.FunClass gets two parameters, number of sets and the lines per set.
The problem is whenever ***update_mytable function*** is being *called* a segmentation fault error pops up.During a *quick search* on *stackoverflow* I read that in most cases the issue for the seg-fault is because we are trying to access to a non-existed vector.But I don't think what I have the same issue here.

```
using std::vector;
typedef vector<mytable_entry>::iterator mytable_iter;

struct mytable_entry
{   
    int x_entry;
    int y_entry;
};

mytable_entry new_mytable_entry(int new_ip, int new_target) {
    mytable_entry new_entry;
    new_entry.ip_entry = new_ip;
    new_entry.target_entry = new_target;

    return new_entry;
}

class FunClass : public BaseClass
{
public:
    FunClass(unsigned mytable_sets, unsigned mytable_lines_per_set)
         : table_sets(mytable_sets), table_assoc(mytable_lines_per_set)
    {
        mytable_table = vector< vector<mytable_entry> > (table_sets,vector< mytable_entry> (table_assoc));

    }

    ~FunClass() {
        /* Vectors will be decontructed automatially out of scope */
    }

    virtual bool predict(int x, int y) {
        /* If mytable_entry exist return true, else false */
        unsigned mytable_set_index = x % table_sets;

        if (find_mytable_entry(mytable_table[mytable_set_index])) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    virtual void update(bool val1, bool val2, int x, int y) {
        unsigned mytable_set_index = x % table_sets;

        if (val1 == val2){
            update_mytable_table(mytable_table[mytable_set_index],ip,target_entry,table_assoc);
        }

    void update_mytable(vector<mytable_entry> & mytable_set, int x, int y,unsigned table_assoc){
        mytable_entry new_entry = new_mytable_entry(ip,target);

        mytable_set.push_back(new_entry);
        if (mytable_set.size() > table_assoc){
            mytable_set.erase(mytable_set.begin());
        }
    }

    bool find_mytable_entry(vector<mytable_entry> & mytable_set, int x) {
        mytable_iter iter;
        for (iter = mytable_set.begin(); iter != mytable_set.end(); iter++){
            if ((*iter).ip_entry == ip) {
                mytable_entry tmp_mytable_entry = (*iter);

                mytable_set.erase(iter);
                mytable_set.push_back(tmp_mytable_entry);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

private:
    vector< vector<mytable_entry> > mytable_table;

    unsigned table_sets, table_assoc;
};
```

If I remove the ***mytable_set.push_back(new_entry);*** from update_mytable everything goes fine then.

Comment: Can you modify your example so that it compiles and does produce the error?

Comment: The segmentation fault occurs at runtime.

Comment: How can you use `mytable_entry` in your `typedef` before defining it ? I mean shouldn't you put your `struct mytable_entry { ..}` before `typedef...` ?

Comment: You probably have some other code that runs before this that causes undefined behavior. It corrupts memory, and it isn't noticed until you call `push_back` here.

Comment: You need to provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want better help than this.